# Difference between count time and discrete time survival analysis

Tags: survival, count-data, discrete-time

Is there a practical or theoretical difference between **count time survival analysis** (e.g. `ctset`/`cttost` in Stata), where counts of events per time-interval is set, and **discrete time survival analysis**, where continuous time to event is treated as discrete. For example, a study where death of participants can only be observed at relatively large (such as 6 or 12-monthly) time-intervals.

Comment: That is what is done I believe with actuarial tables.  Look up the Cutler-Ederer method with a Google search.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I was rather hoping to understand any difference between the two survival analysis techniques. Can you advise?